# How to change displayed buttons based on preferences

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

- I have to use 13 Preferences in my application.
  [image]
- I have 13 buttons for these 13 preferences.
- But i need to display only 4 buttons in active on the home screen, which we have select 4 from these 13 preferences

[image]

- when i click on the preference button (top -right corner to the home page).
  preference list will displayed with 13 preferences.
- When i select any preference the corresponding button should be replaced with the previous button.

  - what to do? thanks in advance

Comment: You have to maintain An array of according to your prefernce you need to change ur first view buttons. Kindly come to gmail i will explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to follow the next:

[if its a limited number of buttons]
1-. Create a IBOutlet for each button.
2-. Maintain a an array for the preferences
3-. Implement an NSNotification in the main screen and call it from preferences, when you dismiss, and send the array
4-. Modify the UIButton

[if its different number of buttons]
- It's almost the same but you need to create them in the code, and then place them. Keep track of the last button x,y,width,height. And the other button could be oldX+oldWidth+offsetX

If you have any problems with the code just tell me